# Multithreading repartition in *nix system

Tags: multithreading

How the reparation of threads per CPU is handle on *nix system? 
For example, one process uses 37 threads, machine has 4 cores. Usually all threads are placed on 2 cores. Sometimes at 3 cores. And almost never on 4 cores.

Is there a way to see what thread is on what core? And how much CPU it uses?

Comment: I'm supposing "reparation" should be "repartition"?

Comment: Which unix? It will make a big difference for a low-level question like this.